# JSON Combine Array with Array of Strings to get a cohesive name value pair

Tags: java, json, splunk

My application is utilizing a 3rd party application to obtain data (Splunk). The output that Splunks api endpoint returns is an Array containing all the row headers and an array of strings containing all the row's data. For example

```
{
    "fields":[
        "appID",
        "ApplicationName",
        "AppOwner",
        "AppOwnerID",
        "KnownIPS",
        "IP Count",
        "KnownFIDS",
        "FIDCount",
        "LastSeen",
        "TotalConnections"],
    "rows":[
        [
            "123456",
            "HelloWorld",
            "Last,First",
            "E12345",
            "11.111.11.111,222.22.22.222",
            "2",
            "A67890,B12345,C67890",
            "3",
            "2019-12-08",
            "47937"
        ]
    ],
    "id":0
}
```

However I would like my output to be something like

```
{
    Field[0]:row[0],
    Field[1]:row[1],
    etc..
}
```

Right now I am able to display the results on my web page using the following

```
 try {

        ArrayList<String> fieldslist = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseString);
        JSONArray fields = json.getJSONArray("fields");

        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("rows"); // JSONArray is from the json.org library
        String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[jsonArray.length()][];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray innerJsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);
            String[] stringArray = new String[innerJsonArray.length()];
            for (int j = 0; j < innerJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                stringArray[j] = (String) innerJsonArray.get(j);
            }
            arrayOfArrays[i] = stringArray;
        }



        if (fields != null) {
            int len = fields.length();
            for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
                fieldslist.add(fields.get(i).toString());

            }
        } ;

        appDetail.setFields(fieldslist);
        appDetail.setRows(arrayOfArrays);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return appDetail;
```

And my Model

```
@JsonProperty("fields")
private List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
@JsonProperty("rows")
private String[][] rows = new String[i][j];

@JsonProperty("fields")
public List<String> getFields() {
    return fields;
}

@JsonProperty("fields")
public void setFields(List<String> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}

public Model withFields(List<String> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
    return this;
}

@JsonProperty("rows")
public String[][] getRows() {
    return rows;
}

@JsonProperty("rows")
public void setRows(String[][] rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

public Model withRows(String[][] rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
    return this;
```

I know I will have to update my model to properly display the correct results, but I cant seem to get the logic correct within the try catch.

Comment: *Right now I am able to display the results*, so what is your question now?

Comment: I am able to display the results in fields,row format but not fields[0],rows[0] etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to convert the response to an object with `fields` to `List<String>` and `rows` to `List<List<String>>`, and then you can display the expected result as follows.

**Class SplunkResponse**

```
class SplunkResponse {
    private List<String> fields;
    private List<List<String>> rows;
    private int id;

    //general getters ans setters
}
```

**Code Snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SplunkResponse response = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, SplunkResponse.class);
Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int row = 0; row < response.getRows().size(); row++) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < response.getRows().get(row).size(); idx++) {
        resultMap.put(response.getFields().get(idx), response.getRows().get(row).get(idx));
    }
}

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(resultMap));
```

**Console Output**

> {"IP Count":"2","ApplicationName":"HelloWorld","AppOwner":"Last,First","KnownFIDS":"A67890,B12345,C67890","KnownIPS":"11.111.11.111,222.22.22.222","appID":"123456","AppOwnerID":"E12345","FIDCount":"3","TotalConnections":"47937","LastSeen":"2019-12-08"}

Comment: This looks like it will solve my issue! I am away from my keyboard for a bit. But will try and mark as answer if applicable asap !

Comment: @Sudosu0 Hi, thanks for your comment and please let me know if my solution solved your problem?

Comment: so sorry for the delay, was away for the holidays. This worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!